# Link to user's profile settings page?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to figure out how to link a logged-in user to his profile settings, but I can't seem to find a function that generates this link (like `wp_settings_url()` or `wp_profile_url()`) 
Is there a default function for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The user edit page of the current user is `/wp-admin/profile.php`, so you can just do `admin_url( 'profile.php' )`, which is the way it is used in the WP source code.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me as well, nice elegant solution. Thanks Jan.

Answer (score 6):

Combination of other answers:

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'user-edit.php?user_id=' . $curauth->ID, 'http' ); ?>">Edit Profile</a>
```

I'm using this on author.php, that's why I've already got the user ID on the page. That way an admin gets a link to edit that user's profile rather than their own.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly something like this?

```
<?php get_currentuserinfo();

global $user_ID;
if (” != $user_ID) { ?>

<a href="/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=<?php the_author_ID(); ?>">Edit
Profile</a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Haven't had chance to check this out but should work!

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in the current user, use [get_edit_profile_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_profile_url/):

```
<a href="<?php esc_attr_e( get_edit_profile_url() ); ?>">
    <?php esc_html_e( 'Link to your profile' ); ?>
</a>
```

If you want to display a link to another user's profile, use [get_edit_user_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_user_link/):

```
<?php
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );
if ( $user ):
    ?>
    <a href="<?php esc_attr_e( get_edit_user_link( $user->ID ) ); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( $user->user_login ); ?>
    </a>
    <?php
endif;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the Correct way! Please use this for user profile link.

```
<?php echo admin_url( 'user-edit.php?user_id=' . $user_id, 'http' ); ?>"><?php echo ucwords( wpe_get_user_name( $user_id ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is better? You're using admin_url just like d3l3t3m3's answer, admittedly without the force-scheme-http-not-s, but without actually constructing a link.